# Getting a segmentation fault when trying to insert into a sorted linked listed

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm just trying to insert random integers into a linked list in a sorted manner.

```
node_type *head=NULL;

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
 {
    input=rand()%101;
    insert(input,&head);
 }
```

Function definition for `insert()`:

```
void insert(int input,node_type **  list)
{
   node_type * temp=malloc( sizeof(node_type));
   if(temp==NULL)
      printf("Error,memory allocation unavailable");

   (*temp).num=input; // filling up with the user's input

   node_type *tempHead=*list; 
   node_type *prev=NULL;

   if(tempHead==NULL) // if list is empty, I simply insert the node at start of list
   {
      (*temp).link=*list;//inserting it at the start of the list
      *list=temp;
      return;
   }

   while( (tempHead->num)<=input && tempHead!=NULL)
   {
         prev=tempHead;
         tempHead=(*tempHead).link;
   }

   prev->link=temp; //Preceding node of new node now points to new node
   temp->link=tempHead; //new node points to succeeding node

}
```

It seems that the segfault happens after looping through this section of code once

```
while( (tempHead->num)<=input && tempHead!=NULL)
       {
             prev=tempHead;
             tempHead=(*tempHead).link;
       }
```

Edit:

Definition of `node_type`:

```
typedef struct node_type node_type;

struct node_type
{
   int num;
   node_type *link;
};
```

Seems like a stupid question but I couldn't seem to figure out what went wrong in this section of code

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't do: (e.g.) `(*temp).num` but, rather, `temp->num` It is _much_ more readable. Also, for something this small, please post your _entire_ program as a _single_ code block. It should be able to be downloaded, compiled [cleanly], and run [if a responder so chooses].

Comment: You're dereferecing `tempHead` before verifying that it's not `NULL`.

Comment: @CraigEstey I'll try to stick with using the arrow operators then. I just wanted to give a MRE so I didn't post the entire program.

Comment: @StephenNewell Doesn't the `while( (tempHead->num)<=input && tempHead!=NULL )` verify `tempHead` is not NULL?

Comment: It checks whether `tempHead` is `NULL` after you dereference it.  I'd expect switching the left and right hand sides of `operator &&` should fix this segfault.

Comment: @StephenNewell  Ah makes sense, thanks

Comment: See `addinorder()` in [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) Using a *pointer-to-pointer-to-node* eliminates the need to keep track of a `prev` pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several subtle problems with your code.

1. The one mentioned in the comment. In the while loop, you dereferenced `tempHead` before testing it for NULL value.

Take the following expression as example: `( tempHead->num<=input && tempHead!=NULL)` The logical operators evaluates expression in-order and short-circuits. This means `tempHead->num<=input` is evaluated first, and if `tempHead` is NULL, it SegFaults.

2. You didn't properly handle `prev` being NULL right after the while loop.

This is because you simultaneously tested for `tempHead` being non-NULL **and** node value satisfying the list order. Therefore, even if `tempHead` is non-NULL, you could still miss the chance to assign to `prev`.

After you've traversed to the point where you can instert the `temp` node into the list, you should test for `prev` before dereferencing in the assignment `prev->link=temp;`. At this point, you need to handle 2 cases:

1. you're in the middle of the list, and
2. you're at the beginning of the list and `prev` is NULL.

I'll just post a whole working example and let you compare the difference. This is a hard practice, and even the most professional C programmers can miss these types of flaws

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node_type node_type;

struct node_type {
    int num;
    node_type *link;
};

node_type *head=NULL;

void dump()
{
    for(node_type *n=head; n; n=n->link)
        printf("%d ", n->num);
    printf("\n");
}

void insert(int input,node_type **  list);

int main()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        int input=rand()%101;
        printf("i=%d, input=%d\n", i, input);
        insert(input,&head);
    }
    dump();
}

void insert(int input,node_type **  list)
{
    node_type * temp=malloc( sizeof(node_type));
    if(temp==NULL)
        printf("Error,memory allocation unavailable");
    memset(temp, 0, sizeof(node_type)); // [Problem 0]: Initialize the structure.

    temp->num=input; // filling up with the user's input

    node_type *tempHead=*list; 
    node_type *prev=NULL;

    if(tempHead==NULL) // if list is empty, I simply insert the node at start of list
    {
        //temp->link=*list; // [Problem 1]: This statement caused a loop list.
        *list=temp;//inserting it at the start of the list
        return;
    }

    //while( (tempHead->num)<=input && tempHead!=NULL) // [Problem 2]: wrong condition expression
    while( tempHead!=NULL && tempHead->num <= input ) // this is the correct expression order.
    {
        prev=tempHead;
        tempHead=tempHead->link;
    }

    if( !prev ) // tempHead != NULL but tempHead->num < input.
    {
        temp->link = *list;
        *list = temp;
    }
    else // we're in the middle of the list.
    {
        printf("%p, %p, %p, \n", prev, temp, tempHead);
        prev->link=temp; //Preceding node of new node now points to new node
        temp->link=tempHead; //new node points to succeeding node
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to understand the 2nd problem where my `prev=NULL`. As a result, I also don't understand the 3rd problem. Although I don't understand the 3rd problem, why would there be a loop due to the if clause if there is a `return` statement in it.

Comment: Sorry, for the delay. There's problem discovered as I'm updating the answer. Please re-read again and tell me your confusion.

Comment: Thanks, I now seem to understand your `while` loop(although I don't know why your code doesn't print them in order) but shouldn't `while(tempHead!=NULL && (tempHead->num)<=input)` work the same?

Comment: `while(tempHead!=NULL && (tempHead->num)<=input)` won't work the same because if the second condition `(tempHead->num)<=input` is false, `prev` will still not get assigned.

Comment: Isn't that a good thing? Since now `prev` points to the preceding node of the node(`tempHead`) that has larger value than input, we can now  `prev->link=temp` and `temp->link=tempHead` correctly(ie insert the new node in the correct position)?

Comment: That won't be the case. If you insert the node at the head, you need to add a special case to handle `prev` being NULL. It's similar to the one you've done in the if clause, but with more code that handles prepending.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a functionally correct example. You can swap out mine and yours to see what part causes what problems.

Comment: Thanks to your example, I realised that the 2nd issue with my program  is that I didn't have the `if( ! prev)` case. By the way, you wrote `tempHead != NULL but tempHead->num < input` instead of  `tempHead != NULL but tempHead->num > input` Also, the part where you wrote `[Problem 1]` won't cause a loop list as my `*list` was initialised to NULL(my bad, I didn't specify)